# Deploy my common folder along with war

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, maven-2

I am facing the problem to deploy my own folder (Single) which has been created during build time with couple of common jar files.I would like to place them in my artifactory repository and expecting my folder also to be copied along with wars.Currently using Jenkins system as CI tool and Maven is the build tool.PLease help to sort out this.

Comment: mvn deploy and settings.xml with repository for artifactory

Comment: I am new to Maven , can you please provide more details.With example helps alot.Thanks

Comment: example with Nexus : https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21283268-Configure-Maven-to-Deploy-to-Nexus

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want ? Deploy the artifacts you produced with maven into artifactory (a case of `mvn deploy`) ? Download the artifactory artifacts into your final application (a case of devops application) ? There are many points in your questions, and all require clarification.

Comment: Need to Deploy from Jenkin system to Maven artifactory repository using maven plugins.All Wars getting build and deployed in repository, same way my common folder(single) also to be placed at the end of the build.I have super/parent pom.xml and having multiple webapps